# How to add/edit advanced custom fields on custom post type's WordPress REST API?

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields, rest-api, json

I have a custom post type called "notes" and also activated an Advanced Custom Field on that post type called "page_link". I want to add/edit the value of page_link using the REST API but I could not do it. I am only able edit native fields like title and the content. In my console, after success, noteLink is there but is equals to "null".

I have html like this:

```
<div class="mb-3">
  <label for="formInput1" class="form-label">Title</label>
  <input id="formInput1" class="new-note-title form-control" placeholder="Title">
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
  <label for="formTextarea1" class="form-label">Content</label>
  <textarea id="formTextarea1" name="" class="new-note-body form-control" placeholder="Content"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
  <label for="formInput2" class="form-label">Link</label>
  <input id="formInput2" class="new-note-link form-control" placeholder="Link">
</div>
```

javascript:

```
createNote(e) {

    var ourNewPost = {
        'title': $(".new-note-title").val(),
        'noteLink': $(".new-note-link").val(),
        'content': $(".new-note-body").val(),
        'status': 'publish'
    }

  $.ajax({
    beforeSend: xhr => {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("X-WP-Nonce", myData.nonce)
    },
    url: myData.root_url + "/wp-json/wp/v2/note/",
    type: "POST",
    data: ourNewPost,

    success: response => {
        //location.reload()
        console.log("Congrats")
        console.log(response)
    },
    error: response => {
      console.log("Sorry")
      console.log(response)
    }
  })
}
```

register post type like this:

```
function custom_post_types() {

    register_post_type('note', array(
      'capability_type' => 'note',
      'map_meta_cap' => true,
      'show_in_rest' => true,
      'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'advanced-custom-fields'),
      'public' => false,
      'show_ui' => true,
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Notes',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Note',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Note',
        'all_items' => 'All Notes',
        'singular_name' => 'Note'
      ),
      'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-welcome-write-blog'
    ));
  }
```

register_rest_field on my functions.php like this:

```
function custom_rest(){

register_rest_field('note', 'noteLink', array(
  'get_callback' => function(){return get_field('page_link');}
));

}

add_action("rest_api_init", 'custom_rest');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only thing missing here is an `update_callback` in the call to [`register_rest_field`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_field/).

```php
    register_rest_field( 'note', 'noteLink', array(
        'get_callback' => function(){ return get_field('page_link'); },
        'update_callback' => function( $value, $post ){
            update_field('field_619dacfd37924', $value, $post->ID );
        }
    ));
```

An important part of that according to [ACF docs](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/) is using the field key to update the value when there is no value yet set.

> The field’s key should be used when saving a new value to a post (when no value exists). This helps ACF create the correct ‘reference’ between the value and the field’s settings.

The field’s key can be found while editing the field group though you may need turn on the option to show "Field Keys" within "Screen Options" if you haven't done so already. Then look for the "Key" column in the table of the fields. Here's what I see.
[image: field row in ACF field group]

On a separate note, when registering the post type, the `supports` property can be cleaned up to just:

```
      'supports' => array('title', 'editor'),
```

Having 'advanced-custom-fields' in there doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but it's still giving me a null from the response under 'noteLink'. I even tried changing $post->ID to get_the_ID() but still the same. This is the code:

  'update_callback' => function( $value, $post ){
      update_field('group_5cbe85832bdaf', $value, get_the_ID() );
  }

Comment: I suspect that key is not the field’s key. I updated my answer detailing a bit more where to find the key (including a screenshot). Also, I'd trust `$post->ID` over `get_the_ID()` in this context but maybe the latter would work fine. I've not tested it. I have tested the former.

Comment: When I read your comment, I was sure I would say: "No, I'm certain that's the field key" and I was so relieved that I was wrong. It wasn't the field key. I was looking at the field's group on the main page of the plugin. You are an angel and please have some of my reputation.